# Avoid using @observable in Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, observable

From this link:

http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/09/forms-http-servers-and-polymer-with-dart.html

I know that it is possible to observe Object values, but how can I avoid using @observable for every variable in the Class. In that way I don't need to put @observable many times. So instead of:

```dart
class Person extends Object with Observable {
  @observable String name;
  @observable String age;
}
```

Just have:

```dart
class Person {
  String name;
  String age;
}
```

Comment: No problem, just don't add it ;-) Seriously, if you want to get notified or want Polymer to get notified about changes you have to apply it. If you don't need this you don't need to add `@observable`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I haven't never used it but as far as I remember you can apply `@observable` on the class too.

I'll check and update the answer...</strike>

```dart
@observable
class Person extends Object with Observable {
  String name;
  String age;
}
```

#### EDIT

I have mixed this up with `@reflectable`. `@observable` needs to be applied to every field individually.

```dart
class Person extends Object with Observable {
  @observable String name;
  @observable String age;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking on something similar to angular where you don't need to add observable

Comment: The Angular team has started to add support for observable recently (in addition to the current behavior) because it is much more efficient to be notified about changes than polling (which is what Angular does).

Comment: My recent comment about Angular seems not to be true for Angular 2. They don't use polling everywhere anymore.